# Finding number of transactions per transaction id

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which one of its columns (tx) contains a list with hundreds of transactions. On another dataframe I have its transaction id(txid) and I need to count how many transactions id there are per transaction.

[image: Here is an image illustrating the 2 dataframes:]

How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Please share a proper sample of dataframe(not images) with input and expected output.

Comment: If you need to count how many transactions are there in the list on `tx` column, you can use `blocks_df = blocks_df.assign(count=lambda x:x["tx"].str.len())`. Or do you also need the frequency with each transaction ID occurs in the list (ex: Transaction[0] -> `{"059C.." : 3, "CBFF.." : 5, etc}`) ?